How to change the style of one border(edge) of a rectangle node, especially overlapping edges of two adjacent nodes?
I want to draw a picture similar to Fig.3.9 in <Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 3rd Edition>, like this

And here is mine using Tikz, basically I use matrix of nodes to draw tables. In process table entry is a matrix of 5-row x 2-column for a file descriptor table, the 1st row and the 5th row span two columns. Other table entires, like file table entry is a 3x1 matrix.

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, matrix, fit, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw=none, font=\scriptsize}, % invisible border
  every matrix/.style={
    draw,
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    inner sep=0pt, % Removes any inner padding within the matrix
  },
  arrows={-{Stealth[inset=0pt, angle=30:10pt]}} % tip angle:30°, dimension:10pt
]
  % process table entry
  \node[
    rectangle, draw, minimum width=58mm, minimum height=50mm
  ] (pte) at (0,0) {};
  %% label
  \node[above=1mm of pte, draw=none] {process table entry};
  % file descriptor table
  \matrix[
    shift={(0.25,-0.15)}, % position, `anchor=center` is default
    nodes={draw, minimum height=5mm},
    column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=1.5cm}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={minimum width=2.5cm}},
    row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},
    row 5/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum height=1.5cm}},
  ](fdt) {
    % 1st row
       & \\
    % 2nd row
    {} & {} \\
    % 3rd row
    {} & {} \\
    % 4th row
    {} & {} \\
    % 5th row
       & \\
  };
  \node[fit=(fdt-1-1)(fdt-1-2)]{• • •}; % 1st row spans two cols
  \node[fit=(fdt-5-1)(fdt-5-2)]{• • •}; % 5th row spans two cols
  %% labels
  \node[above=1mm of fdt-1-1] {fd flags};
  \node[above=1mm of fdt-1-2] {file pointer};
  \node[left=1mm of fdt-2-1] {fd7};
  \node[left=1mm of fdt-3-1] {fd8};
  \node[left=1mm of fdt-4-1] {fd9};

  % file table entries
  \matrix[
    right=30mm of pte,
    anchor=south,
    shift={(0, 5mm)},
    nodes={draw, minimum height=6mm},
    column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=25mm}},
  ](fte1) {
    {file status flag} \\
    {current file offset} \\
    {v-node pointer} \\
  };
  \node[above=1mm of fte1] {file table entry};

  \matrix[
    right=30mm of pte,
    anchor=north,
    shift={(0, -5mm)},
    nodes={draw, minimum height=6mm},
    column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=25mm}},
  ](fte2) {
    {file status flag} \\
    {current file offset} \\
    {v-node pointer} \\
  };
  \node[above=1mm of fte2] {file table entry};

  % arrows from fp to fte
  \draw ($(fdt-2-2.east) - (3mm,0)$) .. controls 
    ($(fdt-2-2.east) + (15mm,0)$) .. ($(fte1.north west) - (1mm,0)$);
  \draw ($(fdt-3-2.east) - (3mm,0)$) .. controls
    ($(fdt-3-2.east) + (15mm,0)$) .. ($(fte1.north west) - (1mm,2mm)$);
  \draw ($(fdt-4-2.east) - (3mm,0)$) .. controls
    ($(fdt-4-2.east) + (15mm,0)$) .. ($(fte2.north west) - (1mm,0)$);

  % v-node table entry
  \matrix[
    right=20mm of fte1,
    nodes={draw, minimum height=10mm},
    column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=30mm}},
  ](vnode) {
    {v-node information} \\
    {v\_data} \\
  };
  \node[above=1mm of vnode] {v-node table entry};

  % i-node
  \matrix[
    below=5mm of vnode,
    nodes={draw, minimum height=7mm},
    column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=30mm}},
  ](inode) {
    {i-node information} \\
    {current file size} \\
    {i\_vnode} \\
  };

  % arrows from fte to v-node
  \draw ($(fte1-3-1.east) + (-3mm,0)$) .. controls
    ($(fte1-3-1) + (20mm,0)$) .. ($(vnode.north west) - (1mm,0)$);
  \draw ($(fte2-3-1.east) + (-3mm,0)$) .. controls
    ($(fte2-3-1) + (25mm,0)$) and ($(fte2-3-1) + (25mm,30mm)$)
    .. ($(vnode.north west) - (1mm,2mm)$);

  % arrows from v-node to i-node
  \draw ($(vnode-2-1.west) + (3mm,0)$) .. controls
    ($(vnode-2-1.west) - (5mm,0)$) .. ($(inode.north west) - (1mm,0)$);
  % arrows from i-node to v-node
  \draw ($(inode-3-1.east) + (-3mm,0)$) .. controls
    ($(inode-3-1.east) + (10mm,0)$) .. ($(vnode.north east) + (.5mm,0)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

My questions:

In the file descriptor table(fdt), to get "span two columns" look, I set draw=none for row 1 and row 5 to hide the two overlapping borders in the middle of two nodes in each row. The other 3 visible borders of row 1 and row 5 nodes come from borders of the matrix itself, row 2 and row 4. Then the problem is all the overlapping borders in row 2, 3, 4 and the matrix itself look heavier(bold) than the borders of row 1 and row 5, which looks imperfect. How to fix this? Possible solutions I can imagine:
a) If an option exists to make overlapping borders not look bold.
b) Remove draw=none for row 1 and row 5, just change the visibility of overlapping borders in the middle, which introduces the 2nd question.

In v-node table entry and i-node matrix, how to modify the style of the overlapping borders in table to dash lines?


Thanks.

Setting row sep=+-.5\pgflinewidth, column sep=+-.5\pgflinewidth, inner sep=+-.5\pgflinewidth for the matrix gives you a cleaner look and makes the lines over lap. You can't (easily) have a rectangular node have different line types per side. You will have to add them later in: \draw[-,dashed] (vnode-1-1.south west) -- (vnode-1-1.south east);. Though, in this case, you will need to set outer sep to zero or auto for the line to line up neatly.

@Qrrbrbirlbel many thanks..The row, column, inner sep part works great, the overlap lines now look normal. And the dash line part, that's a good idea, however, drawing a dashed line alone on a solid line still gives a solid line look, but drawing another thicker(1.5\pdflinewidth) white line before drawing the dashed line works. Like  \draw[-,white,line width=1.5\pgflinewidth]     (vnode-1-1.south west) -- (vnode-1-1.south east);   \draw[-,dashed,line width=1.5\pgflinewidth]     (vnode-1-1.south west) -- (vnode-1-1.south east);
